# JavaFX WebViewer on Java 6?

Tags: java, browser, javafx, java-6

I have at school Java 6 under windows and i can't update it or install the standalone.
I want use JavaFX to have the web viewer in my project.
Is it possible use JavaFX under Java6?
If is possible, How?

**UPDATE**

I want use a web viewer in my project. Is it possible under Java6? Is there a different free library?

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run the older version of JavaFX runtime on Java 6 only on Windows. The runtime is available in the [Java archives](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx2-archive-download-1939373.html).

Please go through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13697212/1759128) for better understanding on why Java 6 is no longer recommended.

**Update**

Do check out [Self Contained Application Package](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/self-contained-packaging.htm), you can create self contained packages of your application which will contain the JRE along with it and doesn't require the system to have prior Java installation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will. Though it will not run out of the box. You might have to perform some configurations and might have to install the standalone too. Though it completely depends on which update of Java6 you have.
If you wish to develop a new JavaFX application, target a minimum version of Java 7u9 because Oracle no longer posts updates of Java SE 6 [since February of 2013](http://java.com/en/download/faq/java_6.xml)

Comment: Is possible create a standalone version with java 8 as runtime on my folder project?